# Inheriting App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, app.xaml

Couldn't find the exact scenario I'm trying to produce in other questions.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
 BaseApplication
    * App.xaml
    * App.xaml.cs

 SpecificApplication
    * App.xaml : BaseApplication.App.xaml
    * App.xaml.cs : BaseApplication.App.xaml.cs
```

But I get this:

> 'BaseApplication.App' cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML.

Does this mean `BaseApplication`'s `App` class cannot have XAML?